# How to vertically align text beside an image in the footer?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to refine the fluid design of my website, such that it will work down to 480px width. I have a section almost done but am hung up on the footer fixed to the bottom.

It does what i want except i can't get the img to align beside the text in the middle. The img keeps getting pushed down. [Link](http://www.briligg.com/futuremoon.html)

html:

```
<footer>
<div class="bottom" style="width: 30%;">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="bottom" style="width: 30%;">
<div style="text-align: right;">
kim@<br>briligg.com
</div>
<div>
<a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/">
<img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by/4.0/88x31.png" 
title="This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License. If you use this 
work, attribute it to Kim Holder, and briligg.com."/>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom" style="width: 30%;">&nbsp;</div>
</footer>
```

css:

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #000015;

}
div.bottom {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 40px;
    color: #9dab71;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    display: inline;
}

div.bottom div {
        display: inline;
}

div.bottom img {
        float: right;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 2px auto;
}
```

It feels like this should be easy and i'm just missing something. :P

Comment: Switch the order of divs in the footer.

Comment: @j08691 Oddly that helped a bit but didn't fix it completely. But then i checked how the padding and margins were adding up and realized i'd exceeded the height of the footer. Fixed that, now it's fine. Been fiddling and fiddling and didn't see that. Posting always helps somehow. Should i delete the question?

Comment: Up to you. The alternative is to post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @j08691 But it still doesn't work unless the text is *after* the image. Wow, i don't understand that. Thanks! (Now i have to figure out how i can add share buttons and not run into this again...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reduce margins

margin: 5px auto;

instead of float img to right, parent div floated to right

and use display: inline-block; for text

https://jsfiddle.net/kokilajs/pt69y332/6/

```
<footer>
<div class="bottom" style="width: 33%;">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="bottom" style="width: 33%;">
<div style="text-align: right;">
    kim@<br/>briligg.com
</div>
<div id="test" >
<a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/">
<img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by/4.0/88x31.png" 
title="This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License. If you use this 
work, attribute it to Kim Holder, and briligg.com."/>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom" style="width: 33%;">&nbsp;</div>
</footer>
```

**Style :**

```
  footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #000015;

}
div.bottom {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px auto;
    height: 40px;
    color: #9dab71;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    display: inline;
}

div.bottom div {
        display: inline-block;
}


#test{
       float: right;
        margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: @briligg
reload with shift key your browser cashed style
if this is working plz mark it as answer :) It will be help full to others

Comment: Yes, it works properly now, and i deleted my previous comment. I already voted for this actually, but i have not marked either answer as accepted because i used both, and also in the end the code i used was significantly different. Inline-block was the thing that really helped me.

Comment: ok it's not a problem but "it works properly" mean this is the answer. you can see below one is not working properly http://jsfiddle.net/kokilajs/wmjpwpg2/
if you mark this as answer mean this is working properly and it will be relay helpful to other readers

Comment: Alright, i checked and indeed it is true, the 2nd answer doesn't work. Thing is, it did before he changed it.